# How to compile/debug a C++ application in Docker with Visual Studio Code on Windows

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm new on Visual Studio Code and Docker. Now I want to use Visual Studio Code to edit my C++ code and Docker to compile/debug.

I don't know how to write the launch.json and task.json correctly files, so that I can use Docker to compile/debug my C++ application just under Visual Studio Code development environment. Is there a solution for this problem?

Here is my platform information:

OS: Windows 10 
Visual Studio Code: v1.25.1 
OS in Docker: Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)
Compiler in Docker: g++

Answer (score 16):

This answer assumes that you are not trying to do anything with multiple containers... I'm assuming that you just want to use a single container to build some C++ code, and that all of your code is in a folder called `C:\vsc_docker_cc_gdb`. I also assume you have the C++ and Docker extensions from Microsoft installed in Visual Studio Code.

Let's start with a simple C++ file, called hello.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout << "Hello from Docker" << std::endl;
}
```

Let's also add a Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -m64
LDFLAGS  = -m64

all: hello.exe
.PRECIOUS: hello.exe hello.o
.PHONY: all clean

%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)

%.exe: %.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f hello.o hello.exe
```

Here's a Dockerfile that extends `gcc:latest` by adding GDB and gdbserver (note: I'm not sure gdbserver is needed):

```
FROM gcc:latest
LABEL Name=vsc_docker_cc_gdb Version=0.0.2
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install gdb gdbserver
WORKDIR /root
```

Here's .vscode/tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build (in container)",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker run --privileged -v c:/vsc_docker_cc_gdb/:/root vsc_docker_cc_gdb make",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "clean (in container)",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker run --privileged -v c:/vsc_docker_cc_gdb/:/root vsc_docker_cc_gdb make clean",
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "remove containers",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker ps -a -q | % { docker rm $_ }",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "run the code",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker run --privileged -v c:/vsc_docker_cc_gdb/:/root vsc_docker_cc_gdb ./hello.exe",
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "prepare to debug",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker run --privileged -v c:/vsc_docker_cc_gdb/:/root --name debug_vsc -it vsc_docker_cc_gdb ",
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

And finally, .vscode/launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "(gdb) Pipe Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/root/hello.exe",
        "cwd": "/root",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "pipeTransport": {
            "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "pipeProgram": "docker.exe",
            "pipeArgs": ["exec", "-i", "debug_vsc", "sh", "-c"],
            "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [{
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }]
    }, ]
}
```

There are two important things here. The first is that you'll notice that parts of launch.json are referring to paths in the container (/root/) and others are referring to paths on the Windows host (workspaceRoot). That is important.

The second is that you'll need to have a container running, and then you can launch a debug process *into it*. Here's a recipe to go from zero to starting that special container and launching a debugger in it.

- From PowerShell: `docker pull gcc`
- From Visual Studio Code: <kbd>F1</kbd>, *Docker: Build Image* (pick vsc_docker_cc_gdb:latest)
- From Visual Studio Code: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to build the code
- From Visual Studio Code: <kbd>F1</kbd>, *Tasks: Run Task* (pick "remove containers")
- From Visual Studio Code: <kbd>F1</kbd>, *Tasks: Run Task* (pick "prepare to debug")
- From Visual Studio Code: <kbd>F5</kbd> to start the debugger

From there, the Visual Studio Code Debug Console should work, and you should be able to set breakpoints, watch variables, and enter debug commands.

Comment: It's useful to add the `--rm` flag to the docker invocation, so that each container is reclaimed automatically.

Comment: I ended up with the following in the launch.json "pipeArgs": ["run", "--privileged", "--rm", "-i", "-v", "/storage/projects/project1/experiments/docker_debug/src:/root", "dockerdebug:latest", "sh", "-c"],. Notice "--priviledged" to make gdb happy (I guess), mounting the dir, and removing the one-time container on exit as the previous commenter has suggested. Otherwise works perfectly (I'm on linux).

Comment: Is your make file complete? I suspect that it misses `CXX=gcc` line?

Comment: It worked for me only after adding
"sourceFileMap": { "/root": "${workspaceFolder}" }
to the configuration in launch.json. Without it vscode was unable to resolve paths given by the debugger

Answer (score 11):

I set up a minimal working example on GitHub: https://github.com/fschwaiger/docker-cpp-vscode

The idea is as follows, assuming you have the `ms-vscode.cpptools` extension:

1. You need containers with `gcc` and `gdb` installed (can be the same)
2. You build the application in the container
3. You run `gdb` from within the container

#### 1. Get the images for `gcc` and `gdb`

`gcc` is available directly from Docker Hub: `docker pull gcc`. I did not find `gdb` there, so there is a Dockerfile to build it:

```
FROM gcc:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdb
RUN echo "set auto-load safe-path /" >> /root/.gdbinit
```

It builds on `gcc:latest` and installs `gdb`, so you can use the same image to compile and debug. It also sets option `set auto-load safe-path /` in `/root/.gdbinit` to suppress a warning when running `gdb` in the container. Safety should not be a concern for local development.

Build the image using `docker build -t gdb .` in the working directory, or in Visual Studio Code run the preconfigured task `build docker gdb` from <kbd>F1</kbd> → *Run Task*.

#### 2. Building the application

In the project, run `docker run --rm -it -v ${pwd}:/work --workdir /work gcc make debug` from a PowerShell window in the working directory. Using Visual Studio Code, this can be done by the preconfigured task `make debug` from <kbd>F1</kbd> → *Run Task*.

#### 3. Debug the application

You want to configure Visual Studio Code to run `/usr/bin/gdb` from within the container. You can use the `pipeTransport` option in `launch.json` for that and make it run:

```
docker run --rm --interactive --volume ${workspaceFolder}:/work --workdir /work --privileged gdb sh -c /usr/bin/gdb
```

Explanation:

- `--privileged`: allow binary debugging
- `--volume ${workspaceFolder}:/work --workdir /work`: mount the project folder into the container
- `--rm`: remove the container after exit
- `--interactive`: VSCode will issue interactive commands to the gdb shell
- `sh -c`: defines a shell entrypoint within GDB is run

The overall `launch.json` looks like follows. Notice that `program` and `cwd` are the paths *within* the container. `sourceFileMap` allows the debugger to match the breakpoints with the source files. The rest is the default template stuff from the C++ extension.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Docker",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "build/apps/program",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "/work",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "make debug",
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "sourceFileMap": { "/work": "${workspaceFolder}" },
            "pipeTransport": {
                "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
                "pipeProgram": "docker.exe",
                "pipeArgs": ["run","--rm","--interactive","--volume","${workspaceFolder}:/work","--workdir","/work","--privileged","gdb","sh","-c"],
                "pipeCwd": ""
            },
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this setup, all you need to do is press play in the debug workspace.